# Find new features from two versions of a python package

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to figure out how to find the newly added features from two different versions of a python module.

For example package `fuzzywuzzy-0.15.0` compared to the older version `fuzzywuzzy-0.12.0`.

How can I get the new features in version 0.15.0?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made the post a bit easier to read. In order for people to help you faster, consider posting the code you have so far and where you are stuck. Code can be formatted as outlined in our [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There isn’t an universal way of doing this.

However, there are ways such as viewing the change log of the package (many packages have this, but not all have this), for example, fuzzywuzzy keeps their change log here: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/CHANGES.rst . And here: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/releases .

Another way is that most packages are also on GitHub, which you can view the commit log detailing all the changes.

Other than these, you can also use Github’s compare feature. https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/compare/0.12.0...0.15.0 .